# Is there a directory of Optimization Handbooks for Legend?

Tags: optimization, legend, online-resources

I'm the sort of person that likes looking at optimization guides for d20 related games.  I know directories for handbooks to certain classes/playstyles exist for both D&D 3.5 and D&D 4E, but I can't seem to find anything similar for Legend. **Does Legend have a directory for optimization handbooks?**

Comment: Posted your question to the devs' chat room, some manner of answer should be coming along.

Answer (score 5):

There is no directory, but here are some guides

- GM tips: http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php/topic,1234.0.html
- Spell-casting guide: http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php/topic,1156.0.html
- Just blade guide: http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php/topic,47.0.html
- Mount Guide: http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php/topic,1016.0.html
- Elemental guide: http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php/topic,971.0.html
- low-action spellcsating guide:
  http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php/topic,427.0.html

bear in mind that many of these were written for older versions of the rules, so they should be fact-checked before you use their advice.